# Why can't I change the background of an <li> element?

Tags: html, css

I want to change my `li` element's background, but I don't know why my code doesn't have any effect on it.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLbWx/)

My HTML code is:

```
 <ul id="visit"> 
 <li> 

   <li > 
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=8" title="فایل‌های آفیس را با افزونه جدید کروم را باز کنید">فایل‌های آفیس را با افزونه جدید کروم را باز کنید</a> 
    </li> 
  <li > 
  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=1" title="سلام دنیا!">سلام دنیا!</a> 
  </li> 
   <li >        
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=258" title="دانلود نرم افزار تم ویندوز ۸ IObit WinMetro 2.0 Beta">دانلود نرم افزار تم ویندوز ۸ IObit WinMetro 2.0 Beta</a> 
  </li> 
   <li > 
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=254" title="تنظیم بازی کامپیوتری با  GeForce Experience 1.0.1.0">تنظیم بازی کامپیوتری با  GeForce Experience 1.0.1.0</a> 
   </li> 
   <li > 
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=242" title="دانلود Speak English Like An American کتاب و صوت آموزش مکالمه زبان انگلیسی">دانلود Speak English Like An American کتاب و صوت آموزش مکالمه زبان انگلیسی</a> 
   </li> 
   <li > 
     <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=240" title="دانلود نرم افزار بهینه سازی سیستم AVG PC Tuneup Pro 2013 12.0.4010.19">دانلود نرم افزار بهینه سازی سیستم AVG PC Tuneup Pro 2013 12.0.4010.19</a> 
   </li> 
   <li > 
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=236" title="دانلود مجموعه بازی SolSuite Solitaire 2013">دانلود مجموعه بازی SolSuite Solitaire 2013</a> 
   </li> 
   <li > 
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=224" title="دانلود نرم افزار افیس رایگان LibreOffice v3.6.5">دانلود نرم افزار افیس رایگان LibreOffice v3.6.5</a> 
  </li> 
  <li > 
   <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=214" title="دانلود نرم افزار مخفی کردن ادرس ای پی Hotspot Shield">دانلود نرم افزار مخفی کردن ادرس ای پی Hotspot Shield</a> 
   </li> 
   <li > 
     <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=175" title="دانلود نرم افزارKInovea 0.8.15">دانلود نرم افزارKInovea 0.8.15</a> 
   </li> 

 </li> 


</ul>
```

And my CSS code is:

```
#visit li
{
    border:1px solid red;   
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

I also tried this CSS code:

```
#visit li li
{
    border:1px solid red;   
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

But both of them don't work.

---

i have changed the li place with a tag place and all also change the css code like this

```
    ul#visit  a
    {
        border:1px solid red;   
        background:#F00;
        display:block;
        margin:4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius:5px;

    }
    ul#visit  a:hover
    {
        background-color:#309;
    }
```

It works but my question is firm. Is it that the `background-color` attribute doesn't work on li element?

Comment: Looks fine to me: https://www.dropbox.com/s/emj1axek3skg95c/libg.png What browser are you using? (E.g. IE 7, Chrome 24?)

Comment: i use firefox, IE(version 8), Chrome all browser are updated.

Comment: well, all browsers except IE are updated, if you're on IE 8 :) And in all of those browsers, you're not seeing any red background? What *are* you seeing?

Comment: and nobody is aware that the HTML is invalid? `<ul><li><li>....</li></li></ul>`
If you would correct your HTML, the CSS will work.

Answer (score 1):

It works. [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLbWx/2/) how ever LI elements do not have padding \ margin by default so it looks like a solid block.

add margin or padding to separate them

```
#visit li
{
    border:1px solid red;   
    background-color:#F00;
    margin:1em 0;
}
```

Comment: i have added both margin and padding but it does't work. the margin effected on li element but the padding didn't. also the background color of li element still doesn't change.

Comment: Don't you see the red background?

Comment: yes i don't see the red background? in fact the red border work but the background of the li element doesn't change.

Comment: i want to change only li element background not ul background!!

Comment: @AzadCom: then you should say that in your question. Here's how to ask a question. 1. Describe what code you've written, and how you're running it. 2. Describe what you expect that code to do. 3. Describe what that code is actually doing.

Comment: @AzadCom UL background is not changed. If you will follow that link you'll have a good time

Answer (score 1):

Add `ul` before second `li` starting element and close it as per DOM structure.

```
<ul id="visit"> 
 <li> 
   <ul>
   <li > 


   </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS: use the below for background color

```
background-color:#F00;
```

Comment: you say remove replace li(child element) with ul element. in fact using ul instead of li as child element. i've done it but still the problem doesn't solve

Comment: +1 for finding out that the HTML is invalid and therefore the CSS is not working

Answer (score 1):

```
#visit li
{
    border:1px solid red;   
    background:#F00;
    display:block;
    margin:1px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

set `display: block` or `inline-block` on the li element in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser do you use? I test your code in IE9, Chrome and Firefox, it is ok for all three browser.And I think you shouldn't use the "li" element as the child element of "li" element. You can using the "ul" element as "li" element. So the code is understanding easily.

```
#visit li.secondchild
{
    border:1px solid red;   
    background-color:green;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Set all the "li" element a class attribute,named "secondchild".

Comment: test it to different browser but still doesn't has different. use ul element instead of li element to use as child element.